# Subcaption compatibility with ACM document class

Tags: templates, incompatibility, subcaption, acm

I'm currently working on a paper for an ACM conference and they require me to use the [sigplanconf.cls](http://drupal.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf.cls)

I want to use subcaption, but if I add

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

then I get the following messages :

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
[...]
! Package caption Error: No float type 'copyrightbox' defined.
```

Anyone encounter that problem ? Is there a fix that doesn't require messing with the cls since I'm supposed to use it as is ?

Full MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{sigplanconf}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\conferenceinfo{XXX '13}{Date, Place.} 
\copyrightyear{2013} 
\copyrightdata{[numbers] \copyright2013 IEEE}

\title{Title Text}
\subtitle{Subtitle Text, if any}

\authorinfo{Name1}
           {Affiliation1}
           {Email1}

\maketitle

test

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any error when I load figures. About the warning message, ask them directly about the rules on using subfigures.

Comment: I get a *warning* but no no *error*. In general, it means that the given `documentclass` has its own way of defining the `caption` command

Comment: Is it possible taht it comes from my version of latex then ?

Answer (score 6):

(CW from comments)

The package `caption` is incompatible with the `sigplanconf` class that implements its own method for captions.

If you need to use the class, there's no way to incorporate `subcaption` that relies on `caption` working.

Answer (score 3):

The same error occurs with the sig-alternate template, but  is fixed there by using

```
  \usepackage{caption}
  \DeclareCaptionType{copyrightbox}
  \usepackage{subcaption}
```

This might work for you as well. Reference at: http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2010-September/015596.html

Answer (score 2):

A similar warning is produced when using the [`sig-alternate.cls`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129291/change-caption-style-of-listings-package-without-caption-package?lq=1) style. The issue there is that ACM defined bold captions, so [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129594/8666), just load the caption package with the font option set to bold:

```
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

This way you can freely use the `subcaption` package with the ACM proceedings class, without affecting the (ugly) bold captions they require.

You can include also `skip=\baselineskip` as suggested in the linked answer, but note it will eat more of your paper's space.