# Change caption style of listings package without "caption" package

Tags: listings, captions

Is there a way to change style of a caption in listings without the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package (make it smaller and non-bold)? I am using `\lstnewenvironment` to create my own customized environment and then use listings via this new environment.

I tried to do it with the `caption` package with `\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={scriptsize,tt}}` and it worked, but the problem is that I cannot use `caption` package as it messes up captions in the rest of the document (as soon as I "include" it), and I have to use predefined class.

Thank you for your help!

(EDIT) Class: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls

(EDIT) MEW:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}

\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
\alignauthor
       John Doe\\
       \affaddr{Lorem ispum}\\
       \affaddr{Lorem ispum}\\
       \affaddr{Lorem ipsum}\\
       \email{john.doe@example.com}
}
\date{30 July 1999}
\maketitle



\lstnewenvironment{mycode}[1][]
{
  \minipage[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \lstset{
    captionpos=b,
    language=C,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbersep=3pt,
    #1
  }
}
{
  \endminipage
}
%\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt}}

\begin{mycode}[title=Awesome C program,label=code:AwesomeC]
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
  }
\end{mycode}

If I use "caption" package, caption of the figure changes style (it is no longer bold). Otherwise I cannot change caption of the code...

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  This is a figure
  \caption{Caption of the figure}  
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could just include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that community members can play with. It could include some of your basic [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) settings for starts.

Comment: And also provide a link to the custom class you are using.  It might be easier to see what that class does with captions so that the `caption` package can replicate it.  Did you try loading `caption` with the `[style=base]` option?

Comment: If a document class uses a customised caption layout it usually redefines `\@makecaption`. Since the `listings` package is using this macro to typeset the caption, too, your `listings` caption should follow this design automatically -- otherwise there is something wrong with your document class.

Comment: I use the following class: http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates (Option 2).

Comment: (complete, working) MWE: http://pastebin.com/47NP6HZS

Comment: @Ivan I edited your question to include directly the MWE. I hope it's OK.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, but loading it in the form

```
\usepackage[font=bf,skip=\baselineskip]{caption}
```

so as to preserve the default caption style implemented by the `sig-alternate` document class. Then you can invoke

```
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt}}
```

to change the listings caption format. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[font=bf,skip=\baselineskip]{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{font={small,tt}}

\lstnewenvironment{mycode}[1][]
{
  \minipage[b]{0.3\textwidth}
  \lstset{
    captionpos=b,
    language=C,
    numbers=left,
    basicstyle=\tiny\ttfamily,
    columns=fullflexible,
    showstringspaces=false,
    numbersep=3pt,
    #1
  }
}
{
  \endminipage
}

\begin{document}

\title{The Title}
\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
\alignauthor
       John Doe\\
       \affaddr{Lorem ispum}\\
       \affaddr{Lorem ispum}\\
       \affaddr{Lorem ipsum}\\
       \email{john.doe@example.com}
}
\date{30 July 1999}
\maketitle

\begin{mycode}[title=Awesome C program,label=code:AwesomeC]
  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return 0;
  }
\end{mycode}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  This is a figure
  \caption{Caption of the figure}  
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  This is a table
  \caption{Caption of the table}  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]