# subcaption: `caption' package not loaded

Tags: subfloats, subcaption, acm

I am trying to use subfig in ACM class file, but it issues an error that 'caption' package not loaded. I downloaded the 1.3 version of caption (as suggested by ACM), but still the same.
Here is the code

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{graphicx, booktabs, multicol,multirow,bigstrut,rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{figures/fig3} \caption{Comparison} \label{Fig:Speed}
 \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
 \includegraphics[scale=0.12]{figures/fig3} \caption{Comparison} \label{Fig:Time}
  \end{subfigure}%
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

when compiling there are couple of errors including:

1. subcaption: `caption' package not loaded
2. Environment subfigure undefined. \begin{subfigure}
3. Missing number, treated as zero \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: The package `caption` (and so also `subcaption`) is not compatible with the `sig-alternate` class.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Any other option? Subbottom also does not work

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129594/41085

Comment: The suggestion of @Crissov solves the problem, by restoring the (ugly) boldface captions that ACM requires, so why is the [below answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156825/8666) accepted ? (it is correct, but leads people to not use the `subcaption` package, which is newer and maintained).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `sig-alternate` defines its own `\caption` command, the `caption` package is not really compatible with it; `subcaption` *might* work, but the result is not guaranteed. You can do with `subfig`:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx} % just for the example
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\subfloat[Comparison one]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/fig3}%
  \label{Fig:Speed}%
}

\subfloat[Comparison two]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figures/fig3}%
  \label{Fig:Time}%
}
\end{figure}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The two lines marked `just for the example` are for producing the image, don't use them yourself.

Don't use `scale=`, but prefer setting the width. You should probably use multiples of `\columnwidth` rather than `\textwidth`, as the class produces two column documents.

[image]

Comment: great. it works perfect.