# 2 images in a row. Subcaption package give me errors, Subfig too , ¿solution?

Tags: subcaption

I have a big .tex that runs well without errors

I´m trying to put 2 images in a row,

I tried subcaption packaes and only adding to my code

```
\usepackage{subcaption} gives me this errors
```

[image]

and then readin this post 
[subcaption: `caption' package not loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156817/subcaption-caption-package-not-loaded)

I use this

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

and.... ERROR too.

so,... how can I put 2 images in a row?

Comment: So you must have a package that you're including that already defines a `subfigure` counter. If it's not [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) or [`supcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption), what about the obsolete [`subfigure`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure)?

Comment: @Werner You´re right!!! :-)) I have in my multiple lines of usepackage... that package :-))  so... In this point... What do you recomend me to use?  If you want, answer the question and I´m marking as solved

Comment: It's such a minor problem, I think we can defer it to an FAQ on obsolete packages: [How to keep up with packages and know which ones are obsolete?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3910/5764)

Comment: @werner Thank You very much for the 1st comment and for this suggestion.