# 'Copyrightbox' becomes 'Table' caption prefix

Tags: tables, captions

I'm quite new to LaTex ACM sig-alternate template and I'm preparing a camera ready version for a proceeding. At first the latex engine gave me the error of `no float type 'copyrightbox' defined` then i followed the thread [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86603/subcaption-compatibility-with-acm-document-class) and added `\DeclareCaptionType{copyrightbox}` like so:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}
```

Now my table caption is prefixed by 'copyrightbox 1:', 'copyrightbox 2:' and so on instead of the usual 'table 1', 'table 2', ... now its like this: [image]

All my figure captions are unaffected and still display as 'Figure 1', 'Figure 2' and so on.

Here is the **mwe** for placing my table:

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | r | }
\hline
& Without BSDiff & With BSDiff \\ \hline \hline 
Storage Space & 9.8mb & 60kb \\ \hline
Fuzzing Time (if no crash) & 1018s & 1105s \\
Creation Time & 63s & 1864s \\ \hline
Network transmission & 8.38s & 0.46s \\ \hline  
\end{tabular} 
\label{fig:FEETPercentage} 
\caption{Percentage uniqueness of first 10 jobs distributed to clients}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I have never encountered this copyrightbox issue and i want to change my caption for table back to 'table n'.

EDIT: I solved the problem by putting a \begin and end table:

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\DeclareCaptionType{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | r | }
\hline
& Without BSDiff & With BSDiff \\ \hline \hline 
Storage Space & 9.8mb & 60kb \\ \hline
Fuzzing Time (if no crash) & 1018s & 1105s \\
Creation Time & 63s & 1864s \\ \hline
Network transmission & 8.38s & 0.46s \\ \hline  
\end{tabular} 
\label{fig:FEETPercentage} 
\caption{Percentage uniqueness of first 10 jobs distributed to clients}

\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you have something like

```
\begin{copyrightbox}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | r | }
\hline
& Without BSDiff & With BSDiff \\ \hline \hline
Storage Space & 9.8mb & 60kb \\ \hline
Fuzzing Time (if no crash) & 1018s & 1105s \\
Creation Time & 63s & 1864s \\ \hline
Network transmission & 8.38s & 0.46s \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{fig:FEETPercentage}
\caption{Percentage uniqueness of first 10 jobs distributed to clients}
\end{center}
\end{copyrightbox}
```

in your document.

You have to change the `copyrightbox` environment to `table` to achieve what you want.

MWE

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| l | c | r | }
\hline
& Without BSDiff & With BSDiff \\ \hline \hline
Storage Space & 9.8mb & 60kb \\ \hline
Fuzzing Time (if no crash) & 1018s & 1105s \\
Creation Time & 63s & 1864s \\ \hline
Network transmission & 8.38s & 0.46s \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{fig:FEETPercentage}
\caption{Percentage uniqueness of first 10 jobs distributed to clients}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note also the use of `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am trying to change from 'Copyrightbox 1' back to 'table 1'. Now it keeps showing up as copyrightbox

Comment: @gigasai Please add a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and not code snippets.

Comment: I have changed to an MWE. Thanks for the guidance, however, I do not have a `\begin{copyrightbox}` in my code. I have only `\begin{tabular}` without `\begin{table}` after adding the enclosing table environment solves the issue.